# Is it right to use "have" in this sentence?

Tags: have-got, have

I was wondering if it's right to say "This is the first car I have ever purchased since I have gotten my driving license".

My question is regarding both of the "I have" usages. Also, when do I need to use “I have” and when not?

thanks

Comment: Note that in the American English, it is a "driver's license".

Comment: In the US it depends on the state.  Mine says "Driver License" at the top.

Answer (score 2):

This sentence sounds odd to me. I would say, "This is the first car I ever purchased since I got my driving license."

**Have** is used with present tense, which is not the case here since you are talking about the past.

Comment: P.S. To make it even more accurate (doesn't relate to what you asked) I would in fact say, "This is the first car I ever purchased after I got my driving license."

Comment: "since" sounds more natural.

Comment: Since has a sense of continuity to it. Since this is an action that has been done at one point of time, 'after' is a better fit.
Since would be a better fit along with continuous actions, for example:
The city's air quality has degraded since the trees in the area were cut down.

Answer (score 0):

I would say “This is the first car I have purchased since I got my driver’s license.”

It is incorrect to use the word “ever” because it is not necessarily the first car you have ever purchased. It is merely the first car you have purchased since you got your license. Perhaps you bought several cars already before you got your license.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that speaker choice (potentially due to cognitive confusion over time references) best accounts for variations in sentences beginning *This is the first time*. See below for additional comments specifically regarding use of *get* in this sentence.

Common convention dictates the use of the present perfect in the phrase

*This is the first/second/third time (that) I* + present perfect

This follows the general rule that experiences in your life until now, generally lacking a specific time reference require the use of present perfect. That said, I can't really see any issue with the use of past simple, even if it sounds a bit strange:

*This is the first time **he hit** the ball out of bounds*

Regarding the *since* clause, the choice of tense is dependent on whether the time phrase describes a point in time, or a period (duration) of time. Note:

*This is the first time I've seen the sun since we arrived in Italy (point in past)*

*This is the first time I've seen the sun since we have been in Italy (duration until now)*

The confusion with the *since* clause in your sentence is due to the use of the verb 'get' which has an evolved meaning of *have* as in *have got* (possession) in addition to its original meaning here of *obtain*. Hence both choices are grammatically accurate depending on the meaning of *got/gotten*

*This is the first car I have ever purchased since I got my driving license (obtained - must be a specific point in time in the past)*

*This is the first car I have ever purchased since I have gotten my driving license (have had - duration, i.e you still have your license now)*

A final point/question, just to throw in a spanner is why we don't use the present perfect in the first verb phrase - as it accurately reflects the rules and usage for the present perfect:

*i.e This has been the first time I have purchased a car....*